# Power BI Prevent Duplicate Removal

Tags: powerbi

It looks like Power BI is doing some form of SQL Union logic when combining data from two or more tables on a table visual.

[image: Image A]

In the image above you can see there are only two rows displayed. Within the data however there are in fact 4 rows, and all are valid to me. When I add another column that is distinct per row, it shows the data I expect. See image below:

[image]

I have two questions, can I change this default behavior? 
If not, can I hide a column within a table visual while still having its data affect the display? That OrderDetailKey has no value to my users, which is why I didn't display it in the first place.

Comment: Is there a value to your users to have identical rows repeated? In other words, why do you want to prevent duplicate removal?

Comment: Actually I discovered this when trying to find a way to display a count of the ProductCategory and stumbled upon this issue. So in this particular case no, they don't need to see the duplicate rows but I need to ensure the count of a given category is correct. 

So, my hope was that if I could prevent this duplicate suppression, I could get the right counts.

This may be more a matter of me not quite understanding how Power BI handles this. I'm coming from a SQL background and I find some of the power bi logic opaque.

Comment: OK. If you add a measure that counts to the table (e.g. `COUNT(TableName[ProductCategoryName])`), you'll see that duplicates aren't removed; they just don't get displayed repeatedly in the table visual. Basically, the table not displaying repeats won't mess up your counts.

Comment: Add an Index Column to the table and make sure it is not summarized.

Comment: Are you sure you are not just aggregating the value in the visual.  Assuming you are using a table visual.  Click on each down arrows of the fields that are being displayed in the table and make sure that No Aggregation is displayed.