# Prevent Power BI to remove duplicated rows when exporting to R custom visual

Tags: r, powerbi, pbiviz

Perhaps related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53950490/1100107).

I'm doing some R custom visuals in PowerBI with the help of **pbiviz**. I encounter a problem: when Power BI sends the data to the R script, it removes the duplicated rows. How to prevent that? Of course I could add an "id" column `1, 2, 3, ...` but this is not convenient because the user would have to select this column whereas it is not used for the visual.